# iOS crash with Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

when I execute this line of code in iOS 8.3 this line crashes:

```
NSArray *results = [self executeFetchRequest:request inContext:context];
```

here is the entire function which fails:

```
+ (id) executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject:(NSFetchRequest *)request inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    [request setFetchLimit:1];

    NSArray *results = [self executeFetchRequest:request inContext:context];
    if ([results count] == 0)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return [results objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

the above function is called by:

```
+ (id)findFirstByAttribute:(NSString *)attribute withValue:(id)searchValue inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{   
    NSFetchRequest *request = [self requestFirstByAttribute:attribute withValue:searchValue inContext:context];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:attribute]];

    return [self executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject:request inContext:context];
}
```

It is worth noting that I am very new to iOS programming so please go easy on me, the question may not be the best and there may not be much backing code but this is due to my lack of knowledge in iOS. My android questions are generally much better than this :P If I am able to add any more detail, I will add more as I can, the crash log is below

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Bad fetch request
>   (NSManagedObjectResultType not compatible with contents of
>   propertiesToFetch)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111d7dc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000110fafbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreData
>
>   0x00000001112ecb6e -[NSSQLGenerator
>   newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] +
>   1646  3   CoreData                            0x00000001112d8dc4
>   -[NSSQLAdapter _statementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 244     4   CoreData                            0x00000001111f0e0c
>   -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 316  5   CoreData                            0x00000001111f0a86 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 118  6   CoreData                            0x00000001111f033c -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] +
>   524   7   CoreData                            0x00000001111efdbb
>   -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 299  8   CoreData                            0x00000001112caa6c __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3356    9   CoreData
>
>   0x00000001112d3c30 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform +
>   192   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114e29614
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114e0f002 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 365    12  CoreData
>   0x00000001112c5245 _perform + 197     13  CoreData
>
>   0x00000001111efa58 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 504  14  CoreData
>
>   0x00000001111ee2ca -[NSManagedObjectContext
>   executeFetchRequest:error:] + 586     15  HawkExpress
>
>   0x000000010e52438e +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord)
>   executeFetchRequest:inContext:] + 62  16  HawkExpress
>
>   0x000000010e52446e +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord)
>   executeFetchRequestAndReturnFirstObject:inContext:] + 78  17 
>   HawkExpress                         0x000000010e5261fc
>   +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord) findFirstByAttribute:withValue:inContext:] + 140     18  HawkExpress
>
>   0x000000010e526274 +[NSManagedObject(MagicalRecord)
>   findFirstByAttribute:withValue:] + 100    19  HawkExpress
>
>   0x000000010e52aa54 +[FavouritesManager doesFavouriteExist:] + 84  20 
>   HawkExpress                         0x000000010e4de4a7
>   -[BookCabViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 2087  21  UIKit                               0x00000001124b9a28 -[UITableView
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508     22  UIKit                               0x0000000112498248 -[UITableView
>   _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2853   23  UIKit                               0x00000001124ae8a9 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 210  24  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000112438a2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
>   + 536     25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fdfbec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146     26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fdf06d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
>   380   27  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fdf0546
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24    28  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fd5c886
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242   29  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fd5da3a
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462    30  QuartzCore                          0x000000010fd5e0eb
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89     31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111cb0ca7
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111cb0c00
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368  33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111ca6a33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123    34  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000111ca6366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     35  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000114a34a3e GSEventRunModal + 161  36  UIKit
>   0x00000001123b8900 UIApplicationMain + 1282   37  HawkExpress
>   0x000000010e4baa23 main + 99  38  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000114e5d145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: I think the title of your question could be better; it got everything to do with Core Data and not very much to do with `NSArray`.

Comment: Feel free to change it or let me know what it should be please, as I said in the question, iOS is not my area, and I have no idea what is going on

Comment: problem is in  this part, please post the code >>>>  NSFetchRequest *request = [self requestFirstByAttribute:attribute withValue:searchValue inContext:context];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:attribute]];

Comment: have you solved this problem now? was any of the answers helpfull? please comment if not or vote/accept if yes ;)

Comment: I have an external iOS developer looking into this now, when I find out what the errors were caused by I will post the answer below, if required I will write my own answer, or I will accept someones answer if they were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the NSArray results is nil before you can do a count.

```
if (array != nil) {
    NSUInteger count = [array count]; // May be 0 if the object has been deleted.
    //
}
else {
    // Deal with error.
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

Comment: Do you?  Since when has Objective-C cared about sending a message thru a `nil` object pointer?

Comment: This answer won't help, its failing when I create an array here: NSArray *results = [self executeFetchRequest:request inContext:context]; not when I do a count

Comment: Did you set the request Entity? NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

Answer (score 0):

tried to comment out the line `[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:attribute]];`?

**'Bad fetch request (NSManagedObjectResultType not compatible with contents of propertiesToFetch)'** means, that you seem to expect the default `NSFetchRequestResultType` (`NSManagedObjectResultType`). But you request not to fetch the complete Entity, but only **ONE** attribute (why, just by the way? Your method provide an expected value and gives only one attribute to fetch).

My solution to this:

```
- (id)findEntityNamed:(NSString*)entity withKeyPath:(NSString*)path equalTo:(id)value
{
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity
                                    inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    NSPredicate* predicate = 
    [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:path]
                                   rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:value]
                                          modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                              type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType
                                           options:0];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];            // ONLY 1 OBJECT IS FETCHED!

    NSError* err = nil;
    NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
    [fetchRequest release];

    if( err )
    {
        // do logging stuff etc.
    }

    if( [results count] < 1 )
        return nil;

    return [results lastObject];
}
```

you can try this and tell if this is more like you was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your NSFetchRequest object is probably not constructed correctly.

Here is a valid NSFetchRequest example. Find plenty more by googling "NSFetchRequest example".

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", aTitle]; //<----- (a)
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:moc]]; 
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Be careful at (a), the string must strictly follow the predicate format string pattern (see NSPrediate class reference), name must be a property of Person entity in your managed object model

And the problem is in this part

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [self requestFirstByAttribute:attribute withValue:searchValue inContext:context]; 
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:attribute]];
```

So, post the code for method [self requestFirstByAttribute... ] if still not resolved.